# Connecting QDateEdit and QTimeEdit widgets to corresponding Field in QGIS layer

Tags: qgis, spatialite, qt

Could anybody give me a hint how to connect the QDateEdit and the QTimeEdit widgets with a field in a QGIS layer (shp or spatialite)?

The fields in the QGIS layers are from datatype "date" (dd.MM.yyyy) and "datetime" (HH:mm). ObjectName in **Qt-Designer** and the layer in QGIS are equal. For some reason the connecting doesnt work and the entry in my table stays "NULL". The binding with normal LineEdits works. I tried to describe my problem [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84429/binding-between-qgis-custom-form-qt-designer-and-date-time-field-in-a-spatiali) but obviously I wasn't that precise.

I'm not a programmer and until now I haven't worked with C++.

Answer (score 1):

The use of Qt native widget (QDateTimeEdit) is now possible in QGIS, since QGIS 2.4.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/431b065