# QGIS 2.0: Date Field for Custom Feature Form

Tags: qgis

I see a lot of posts regarding a customizable date field for a QGIS custom feature form such as [this one](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/30896) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84429/binding-between-qgis-custom-form-qt-designer-and-date-time-field-in-a-spatiali). I cannot bind my fields with a line edit, combo box, nor dateEdit. Is there any known solution to this issue?

This is what happens when I try to with a QDateEdit widget in PyQt Designer and set the widget in QGIS to Calendar. Changing the dateEdit doesn't update the value. The calendar widget successfully opens and sets the date, but it is not at all placed in the correct place on the form.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is assigning the QLineEdit control to a text field with the following settings:

[image]

Comment: Good for now--it's too bad, though, that the calendar widget doesn't work for feature forms for now. please do drop a line if you ever find another solution using the calendar widget.